# How to combine 2 ideally rows that met specific conditions from a dataframe into another dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I am new to pandas. Now I successfully retrieve the 2 rows with seperated 'return' code as below:

```
df = pd.read_csv ('all_time_olympic_medals.csv')
df2 = df.iloc[:-1]                      
return df2[df2['no_summer_golds']==df2['no_summer_golds'].max()]
return df2[df2['no_winter_golds']==df2['no_winter_golds'].max()]
```

The question is how to make it to dataframe shape (2, 17) as below:

```
    >>> the_king_of_summer_winter_olympics.shape
(2, 17)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with chain conditions by `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
return df2[(df2['no_summer_golds']==df2['no_summer_golds'].max()) | 
           (df2['no_winter_golds']==df2['no_winter_golds'].max())]
```

Comment: If i want to add more rows, just add the '|' ? May i know which pandas section should i refer to? You solved my problem and thank you.

Comment: @PTP_XX - `If i want to add more rows, just add the '|'` - yes, chain conditions by `|` for bitwise `OR`